# Multiple nested tabs alternative?

Tags: tabs, nested-tables

I am working on a web app for ipad and the app has nested architecture. As you see in the image we have like 3 levels of nested tab.  The level 1 header has items on right side which I haven't shown and also makes it busy.

[image]

I wanted to know if there are better ways to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interactivity with tabs offers many possibilities, including swapping the labels for titles (and subtitles) when they are active, suppressing the rest of the tabs plus a return icon in each state when advancing to the following steps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've noted that when you have such deep nested hierarchies, most designs switch to a horizontal column system (let's call it that for now).

[image: 3 columns]

Something like that.

You can also see this in Google Analytics:

[image: Google analytics admin section]

Firebase Firestore as well:

[image: Firebase firestore data viewer]

Comment: I like the idea and had similar thoughts. One think I forgot to add was this is for a iPad mini POS app ( 1133*768), thats why vertical layout was used to give more space to the final content.